# Unable to store data in table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO sampledata (name, email, pasword)
VALUES (tony, tonymail, 123pass);
```

above is the query I am writing to store some data inside my table which has column as following

```
id AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name varchar(50),
email varchar(50),
password varchar(50);
```

BUT I AM GETTING ERROR ~

> Unknown column 'tony' in 'field list

Comment: The value needs to be surrounded by quotes. `'tony', 'tonymail', '123pass'`.

Comment: That looks obvious, as all values need to be put in quotes

Comment: ___Additional Note___ If the column is called `password` then this is also wrong `INSERT INTO sampledata (name, email, pasword)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is MySQL, you are supposed to put the VALUES in quotation.

So what you should be writing is

INSERT INTO sampledata (name, email, password)
VALUES ("tony", "tonymail", "123pass");

Comment: This has nothing to do with MY SQL, but with the data type. Strings must also be quoted in other DB's.